How to find storage size of tables in DuckDB?
I'd like an approximation of how much of my duckdb file size (750MB) comes from different tables. How can I do this?

I believe there is no such function as of version 1.0.0. However, you could estimate the size based on the following query:
select * from duckdb_tables();

See https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/meta/duckdb_table_functions.html
The column estimated_size displays the estimated number of rows in the table. The column_count gives the number of columns.
You could use
describe mytable

or
SELECT * FROM duckdb_columns()
 WHERE table_name='mytable'
   AND NOT internal;

where mytable is the name of your table. You obtain the size of each column in the table using
type_size from
select * from duckdb_types();

Here is a possible solution. You need to change the string mytable to the name of your table.
-- Define the table name in a CTE
WITH table_name_cte AS (
    SELECT 'mytable' AS table_name
),
table_info AS (
    SELECT
        t.table_name,
        t.column_count,
        t.estimated_size
    FROM duckdb_tables() t
    JOIN table_name_cte cte ON t.table_name = cte.table_name
),
column_info AS (
    SELECT
        c.table_name,
        c.column_name,
        c.data_type,
        CASE
            WHEN c.data_type    = 'BOOLEAN'   THEN  1
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'TINYINT%'  THEN  1
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'SMALLINT%' THEN  2
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'INT%'      THEN  4
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'BIGINT%'   THEN  8
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'FLOAT%'    THEN  4
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'DOUBLE%'   THEN  8
            WHEN c.data_type LIKE 'VARCHAR%'  THEN 24 -- Estimated average size for VARCHAR
            ELSE                                    8 -- Default size for other types
        END AS type_size
    FROM duckdb_columns() c
    JOIN table_name_cte cte ON c.table_name = cte.table_name
    WHERE NOT c.internal
)
SELECT
    t.table_name,
    t.estimated_size,
    t.column_count,
    SUM(c.type_size * t.estimated_size) AS estimated_table_size
FROM table_info t
JOIN column_info c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
GROUP BY t.table_name, t.estimated_size, t.column_count;


I scoured through the DuckDB documentation and there does not seem to be an easy solution here. Here is an item on DuckDB's discussion board that you could look at (this merely suggests that others have the same issue).
